# FrameLayout not appearing under text view

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to create a `RelativeLayout` dynamically but for some reason, the custom view is being drawn on top of the text view. Does anyone know what is going wrong and how to place the text view above the drawing?

```
public class MyRLayout extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public MyRLayout() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_relativelayout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getView();
        assert v != null;

        RelativeLayout relativelayout = v.findViewById(RelativeLayout_custom);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsP1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        // add text view
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(getActivity());
        tv1.setText("Hello World");
        TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(tv1, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
        tv1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        // set view for drawing1
        FrameLayout frameLayoutP1 = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        paramsP1.height = fortyDp;
        Drawing1 cvDrawing1 = new Drawing1(getActivity());
        cvDrawing1.setLayoutParams(paramsP1);
        frameLayoutP1.addView(cvDrawing1);

        // generate IDs for views
        tv1.setId(View.generateViewId());
        frameLayoutP1.setId(View.generateViewId());

        // set RelativeLayout rules for views
        paramsP1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv1.getId());

        // setLayoutParams for views
        tv1.setLayoutParams(rlp1);

        // add views to RelativeLayout
        relativelayout.addView(tv1);
        relativelayout.addView(frameLayoutP1);

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  tv1.setLayoutParams(rlp1);
```

should be

```
  tv1.setLayoutParams(paramsP1);
```

(the one you added the below rule to)

You're setting the wrong LayoutParams.

Comment: You're suggestion places the text view under the drawing. How can it be placed ABOVE the drawing?

Comment: @MacaronLover By placing the textview on top and placing the drawing under the textview.

Comment: I already did that but it's not working:         `paramsP1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv1.getId());`

Comment: Why setLayoutParams of the text view to `paramsP1` instead of `rlp1` when the former relates to the `FrameLayout`, and the latter refers to the `TextView`?

Comment: Are you setting the paramsP1 to the drawing? Because you don't in the code you posted. 
Try that, if that doesn't work, update your question with your current code and please use proper names for your variables. This will make it easier for you and us. E.g. call the LayoutParams for your TextView textViewLayoutParams, the LayoutParams for your ImageView imageViewLayoutParams etc.